# Mega + SIM808 GPRS GSM GPS IPX-SMA module power on from code

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

Is it possible to turn on the SIM808 module from code? There is a button in the SIM808 board to activate the module, but I need to turn it on from the code automatically. This is because my device will be stored hidden inside a vehicle so I do not have to keep turn on and off by hand.

[This](https://www.banggood.com/SIM808-Module-GSM-GPRS-GPS-SMS-Development-Board-IPX-SMA-with-Antenna-p-1062818.html) is the model.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pictures it looks like it should be possible to take the two exposed connections of the switch and add flying leads to them and run them back to the microprocessor to allow it to turn them on and off.  The possible problem is the current that has to run through the switch.

You will need to investigate, but it looks like it could be done like that if you can't find a better solution.

Comment: Actually that switch should just be turned on. The problem is with the power button, I need to hold it for about 2 seconds and then release it to fully activate the module functions. That is the problem.

Comment: Sorry I said switch but I meant the button near where it says "Press this to Start"